# Replaced elements of a list do not carry over outside for loop Python

Tags: python, list, variables, indexing, scope

I'm trying to convert a list of numbers into letters and am wondering why my conversions do not carry over outside my for loop. Is it an error with scope? I apolgize for any poorly written code, I'm new to learning Python. Thanks so much.

```
cstring = [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3]

for number in cstring:
    if number == 0:
        number = 'A'
    elif number == 1:
        number = 'C'
    elif number == 2:
        number = 'G'
    elif number == 3:
        number = 'T'

print(cstring)
```

output is 0 3 2 1 0 0 1 3. It should be ATGCAACT.

Answer (score 1):

you can use enumerate and replace by index !!

```
cstring = [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3]

for num,ele in enumerate(cstring):
    if ele == 0:
        cstring[num] = 'A'
    elif ele == 1:
        cstring[num] = 'C'
    elif ele == 2:
        cstring[num] = 'G'
    elif ele == 3:
        cstring[num] = 'T'

print("".join(cstring))
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to modify a list while you are iterating through it.  It won't hurt in this case, but it's not good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i just read the some stuffs relates to that i will keep in mind!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change a variable in an array, you must define its index. You could do it is by creating a variable that moves along the for-loop that represents the current index.

```
cstring = [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3]

i = 0
for number in cstring:
i += 1
    if number == 0:
        number[i] = 'A'
    elif number == 1:
        number[i] = 'C'
    elif number == 2:
        number[i] = 'G'
    elif number == 3:
        number[i] = 'T'

print(cstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `number = 'A'`, you are just changing the value of the `number` variable.  That variable has no connection to the old list.  The BEST way to handle something like this is to build up a new list with the new valiues:

```
cstring = [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3]
dna = []

for number in cstring:
    if number == 0:
        dna.append('A')
    elif number == 1:
        dna.append('C')
    elif number == 2:
        dna.append('G')
    elif number == 3:
        dna.append('T')
print(dna)
```

but there are better ways.

```
dna = ["ACGT"[number] for number in cstring]
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop copies each value from the array into the loop variable `number`. Since we're just copying the value, an assignment like `number = 'A'` has no effect on the original array.

Instead, you should use assignments with the array itself, i.e. do something like `cstring[i] = 'A'` instead. Try changing the for loop to be

```py
for i in range(len(cstring)):
```